# Could not set innerText for twoCellAnchor using openxml excel C#

Tags: c#, excel, openxml

My requirement is to change the text of the textbox in excel using openxml c#. i can find the textbox using the below code:

```html
WorkbookPart workbookPart = document.WorkbookPart;
                    Sheets sheets = workbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>();


//To add the month in the first KPMG sheet
string sheetName = "Test";
Sheet sheet1 = document.WorkbookPart.Workbook.GetFirstChild<Sheets>().Elements<Sheet>().Where(s => s.Name == sheetName).FirstOrDefault();

string relationshipId = sheet1.Id.Value;

WorksheetPart worksheetPart = (WorksheetPart)document.WorkbookPart.GetPartById(relationshipId);
var ocaElems = worksheetPart.DrawingsPart.WorksheetDrawing.Elements<TwoCellAnchor>();

foreach (TwoCellAnchor twoCellAnchor in ocaElems)
{
if (twoCellAnchor.InnerText.Contains("google"))
{
//twoCellAnchor.InnerText = "Ted Report - August";
//while setting innerText its showing error as set is not accessible
                                
}

                       
 }
```

Comment: We cannot assign string to TwoCellAnchor element.